# How to get associated items through a middle class in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think this may be a pretty simple ActiveRecord problem to solve but if I have a query like:

```
@store = Store.find params[:id]
@categories = @store.categories.all
```

where say `@categories = @store.categories.all` returns like 3 objects. I then want to do a query where I get all of the associated `items` that have that same category_id, I tried:

```
@categories.items
```

But it didn't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is, say, if we have category 1, category 2, and category 3, you want all items that belong to any of those categories. Is that right?

This *could* be solved via iteration or manual conditions on a single query, but it sounds like the job for `has_many :through`.

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, :through => :categories
end
```

After that, `@store.items` should return all items that belong to any of the store's categories. A store has a relationship with certain items through the category object.

If you're wary of creating that relationship (though it's definitely the simplest and least fragile way to go), you could also do this procedurally. The naive approach would be to run the `items` method on each category and put the results all in one array, but that would run one query per category: the infamous N+1 problem. If there are 50 categories, then that's 50 queries just to fetch the items. You'd be better off running just one query to find the items you want:

```
@items = Item.where(:category_id => @categories.map(&:id)).all
```

(I'm not *totally* sure on that being the Arel syntax for the classic SQL `WHERE…IN` clause, but I think that's it.)

`@categories.map(&:id)` returns an array of all the categories' IDs, which is passed as the condition for the item's `category_id`. So, in English: "find all items where category_id is in this list of category IDs"

So, there are two one-query solutions that perform about equally well. Go for the one that feels cleaner to you :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
@categories.map(&:items)
```

Answer (score 1):

`@categories` is an array of `Category` items, but the wireup function doesn't exist on the array itself. You need to iterate the array of categories and collect the related items:

```
@items = @categories.map(&:items).flatten
```

`map` by itself will return an array of arrays, each corresponding to the output of `category.items`, so you need to call `flatten` to create a single array of items.

This is a solution to your immediate problem, but @Matchu's post is how you *should* be writing it.

Comment: N+1 problem :( If there are 50 categories, that's 50 queries in that one line.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `@categories` is an array, not a category object. You can do:

```
items = []
@categories.each do |category|
  items = items.concat(category.items)
end
```